# Codeigniter email do not encode to utf8

Tags: codeigniter, utf-8, character-encoding

I am using Codeigniter email library.
I have some data in serbian in database with this type of characters : žčćšđ
When I print it out in other palces, there is all OK with characters, so databese save it on right way.

My controller looks like this:

```
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);


    foreach($email as $val): 

    $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from('rs@svstara.rs', 'Vojvođanska Svaštara - Mali Oglasi');
        $this->email->to('daniela.stevanovic@gmail.com'); 

        $this->email->subject($uid);
        $this->email->message($tekst);  

        $this->email->send();

        $info=$this->email->print_debugger();
         endforeach;
     echo json_encode(array('info'=>$info));
```

When I recieve email it looks lik this: pšđpšđpšđpšđ-čć.-
So there is some characters, what is not encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to encode strings to UTF-8, even if you expect they are already utf-8 encoded. Try php [mb-convert-encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

```
mb_convert_encoding($content, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Ah now it is worse, with that result was someting like this:        Po&scaron;tovani, Zahvaljujemo se &scaron;to koristite portal
sva&scaron;tara.rs Va&scaron; oglas pod naslovom STENCI LAGOTTO ROMAGNOLO u
rubrici&nbsp;&nbsp;Kućni ljubimci i oprema&nbsp;biÄ‡e objavljen kada
primimo kopiju liÄ ne karte na email: administrator@svastara.rs i uplatu
od 110 dinara na na&scaron; raÄ un: Banca Intesa br. 160-15251-10 Za

Answer (score 0):

Check that the file format is UTF-8 too. Sometimes, when using Eclipse, it sets by default to ISO-8859.

Right click on the file > Porperties > Text file encoding: UTF8.

You can apply this to all the project (WARNING: it may break up some characters)